# changing ssh port with ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I want to change port of ssh server on client systems to custom one 2202 (port defined in `group_var/all` and also in `roles/change-sshd-port/vars/main.yml`). My requirement is that the playbook can also be run when port is already set to custom 2202 (then playbook should do nothing).
I already used ansible role basing on solution: https://github.com/Forcepoint/fp-pta-ansible-change-sshd-port

The port is changed fine when I run the script for the first time (when completed I can login client node on new port).
When I run the playbook again it fails because is trying to do some tasks via old 22 instead of new port 2202

```
TASK [change-sshd-port : Confirm host connection works] ********************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [192.168.170.113]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 192.168.170.113 port 22: Connection refused", "unreachable": true}
```

I can't find why it is trying to use port 22 when `ansible_port` variable is set to new port in `roles/change-sshd-port/vars/main.yml`

```
---
# vars file for /home/me/ansible2/roles/change-sshd-port
ansible_port: 2202
```

The part of the role task `roles/change-sshd-port/tasks/main.yml` until failing `ping` task is:

```
- name: Set configured port fact
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    configured_port: "{{ ansible_port }}"

- name: Check if we're using the inventory-provided SSH port
  ansible.builtin.wait_for:
    port: "{{ ansible_port }}"
    state: "started"
    host: "{{ ansible_host }}"
    connect_timeout: "5"
    timeout: "10"
  delegate_to: "localhost"
  ignore_errors: "yes"
  register: configured_ssh

- name: SSH port is configured properly
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "SSH port is configured properly"
  when: configured_ssh is defined and
        configured_ssh.state is defined and
        configured_ssh.state == "started"
  register: ssh_port_set

- name: Check if we're using the default SSH port
  ansible.builtin.wait_for:
    port: "22"
    state: "started"
    host: "{{ ansible_host }}"
    connect_timeout: "5"
    timeout: "10"
  delegate_to: "localhost"
  ignore_errors: "yes"
  register: default_ssh
  when: configured_ssh is defined and
        configured_ssh.state is undefined

- name: Set inventory ansible_port to default
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    ansible_port: "22"
  when: default_ssh is defined and
        "state" in default_ssh and
        default_ssh.state == "started"
  register: ssh_port_set

- name: Fail if SSH port was not auto-detected (unknown)
  ansible.builtin.fail:
    msg: "The SSH port is neither 22 or {{ ansible_port }}."
  when: ssh_port_set is undefined

- name: Confirm host connection works
  ansible.builtin.ping:
```

Comment: What does your inventory entry for this host look like?

Comment: just test host group entry with one test remote client, the ansible_port 2202 is provided in role's vars - I have it also in ansible.cfg set to the same custom value ansible_port=2202 (in ansible.cfg there is also ansible_become=yes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is missing a bunch of details (there's no way for us to
reproduce the problem from the information you've given in the
question), so I'm going to have to engage in some guesswork. There are
a couple of things that could be happening.

First, if you're mucking about with the ssh port in your playbooks,
you're going to need to disable fact gathering on the play. By
default, ansible runs the `setup` module on target hosts before
running the tasks in your play, and this is going to use whatever port
you've configured in your inventory. If sshd is running on a different
port than expected, this will fail.

Here's a playbook that ignores whatever your port you have in your
inventory and will successfully connect to a target host whether sshd
is running on port 22 or port 2222 (it will fail with an error if sshd
is not running on either of those ports):

```
- hosts: target
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    desired_port: 2222
    default_port: 22
  tasks:
    - name: check if ssh is running on {{ desired_port }}
      delegate_to: localhost
      wait_for:
        port: "{{ desired_port }}"
        host: "{{ ansible_host }}"
        timeout: 10
      ignore_errors: true
      register: desired_port_check

    - name: check if ssh is running on {{ default_port }}
      delegate_to: localhost
      wait_for:
        port: "{{ default_port }}"
        host: "{{ ansible_host }}"
        timeout: 10
      ignore_errors: true
      register: default_port_check

    - fail:
        msg: "ssh is not running (or is running on an unknown port)"
      when: default_port_check is failed and desired_port_check is failed

    - when: default_port_check is success
      block:
        - debug:
            msg: "ssh is running on default port"

        - name: configure ansible to use port {{ default_port }}
          set_fact:
            ansible_port: "{{ default_port }}"

    - when: desired_port_check is success
      block:
        - debug:
            msg: "ssh is running on desired port"

        - name: configure ansible to use port {{ desired_port }}
          set_fact:
            ansible_port: "{{ desired_port }}"

    - name: run a command on the target host
      command: uptime
      register: uptime

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ uptime.stdout }}"
```

Comment: What I use/try is 1:1 copy of solution provided on https://github.com/Forcepoint/fp-pta-ansible-change-sshd-port - so I think you have also all there ready to reproduce this problem, don't you?

Comment: When I tried your playbook, it also fails when ssh port on remote system is already set to desired one. For unknown reason it fails on task "check if ssh is running on 2022" - ssh is running in that port there. The error is: TASK [check if ssh is running on 2022] *************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [192.168.170.113 -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "elapsed": 10, "msg": "Timeout when waiting for localhost:2022"}
...ignoring

Comment: This works for me regardless of the port on which sshd is listening. I cannot reproduce the problem you're describing. Here's the playbook running with the host listening on port 22: [example1](https://asciinema.org/a/mnQd07SfXEzJYMxtvyF4II1tJ) Here's the playbook running with the host listening on port 2222: [example2](https://asciinema.org/a/eVcPmKkKi3DqNwhBxeH1Encez).

Comment: Maybe it is related to delegate_to, I tried your playbook in clean ansible setup and can reproduce this problem - I collected all test data in my new ticket https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68056316/issue-with-delegate-to-used-in-ansible-task

Comment: I had to replace ansible_host with inventory_hostname to get it working