# issue with delegate_to used in ansible task

Tags: ansible

Is this the proper behavior that task with "`delegate_to: "localhost"`" is trying to ssh "localhost" and not from the "localhost" (ansible master) to the remote's ssh port?

Playbook fails on:

```
"Timeout when waiting for localhost:2022"
```

Here example configuration I reproduce it with:

Inventory file:

```
[testremote]
192.168.170.113 ansible_user=ja
```

Ansible config file:

```
[defaults]
host_key_checking = False
inventory = hosts
callback_enabled = profile_tasks
ansible_port = 2022
```

Playbook file:

```
- hosts: testremote
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    desired_port: 2022
  tasks:
    - name: check if ssh is running on {{ desired_port }}
      delegate_to: localhost
      wait_for:
        port: "{{ desired_port }}"
        host: "{{ ansible_host }}"
        timeout: 10
      ignore_errors: true
      register: desired_port_check

    - when: desired_port_check is success
      block:
        - debug:
            msg: "ssh is running on desired port"

        - name: configure ansible to use port {{ desired_port }}
          set_fact:
            ansible_port: "{{ desired_port }}"

    - name: run a command on the target host
      command: uptime
      register: uptime

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ uptime.stdout }}"
```

Remote host is accessible on desired port already:

```
[ansible]$ ssh -p 2022 ja@testremote date
Sun Jun 20 16:40:36 CEST 2021
[ansible]$ ping testremote
PING testremote (192.168.170.113) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from testremote (192.168.170.113): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=1.14 ms
```

And result when playbook is run:

```
[ansible]$ ansible-playbook test_playbook.yml

PLAY [testremote] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [check if ssh is running on 2022] *************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [192.168.170.113 -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "elapsed": 10, "msg": "Timeout when waiting for localhost:2022"}
...ignoring

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [192.168.170.113]

TASK [configure ansible to use port 2022] **********************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [192.168.170.113]

TASK [run a command on the target host] ************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [192.168.170.113]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 192.168.170.113 port 22: Connection refused", "unreachable": true}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
192.168.170.113            : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=2    rescued=0    ignored=1
```

Comment: Please edit your question and share your inventory. I strongly suspect you have (re)defined the [implicit localhost](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory/implicit_localhost.html) there and that all your hosts are set to respond on port 2022.

Comment: I have updated my question with the requested data @Zeitounator

Comment: Ok got it after some tries.... `ansbile_host` contains the host your are actually connecting to. When delegating, it contains the address of the delegated machine. Use `inventory_hostname` instead. This will return the inventory name (in your case the ip) of the host in the loop, no matter which host you delegate to. That should fix the current problem.

Comment: Thank you @Zeitounator, your hint fixed my problem indeed.